# I am currently getting this crash log in the console:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
2011-12-01 18:10:36.932 AVCam[3987:17903] *** -[UIImage _isResizable]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xdf7e360

Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

The Code is

```
UIImageView * firstView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 240)];
[firstView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
firstView.image = firstPhoto.photo;
[firstBlock addSubview:firstView];
[firstView release];
```

Does anyone know what this means? What could be the cause of it?

Thanks!

Comment: ios 5 @MisterJack already help me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The problem should be here:

```
firstView.image = firstPhoto.photo;
```

What is `firstPhoto`? When does it get released? I guess it gets deallocated before it becomes the content of that `UIImageView`.

<del>You'll probably have to send a `[retain]` message, something like:

    firstView.image = [firstPhoto.photo retain];</del>

Comment: `UIImageView`'s `image` property is defined as retained, so i'm not sure `[firstPhoto.photo retain]` is really required/ or will help. But your hint towards "What is `firstPhoto`?" should be helpful in identifying the problem. Maybe it has been released/autoreleased before `firstView.image = firstPhoto.photo;`

Comment: I agree, the problem is likely to be with firstPhoto.photo. if you comment out that line it probably doesn't crash? how is firstPhoto.photo created etc.

Comment: Did you add a `[retain]` message? Or did you find a solution in another part of your code? Anyway, think about accepting this answer.